# aggregation query for recordset in VBA

Tags: vba, ado

Can I do aggregation query for a recordset in VBA. the first part code is the following:

```
'' part 1
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM Table1;")  ''' this SQL Statement is a simplified one;the actual one is very complex.
```

RS will be display in sheet 1; then I want to display the result of the following in sheet2:

```
select sum(col1), count(*), sum(col2) from 
(select * from table1) group by 1,2 order by 1,2
```

because rs has been got from the database in part 1, I does not want to re-run the SQL in database, instead I want to get the result of part 2 in VBA's recordset.
I check the method of recordset, it only provides the method of count, move,etc.
Anyone can help me? thanks!

Comment: The fastest will most likely be to run an aggregating query. But if you insist, loop the recordset (`rs`) and _sum_ the values and _count_ the records as you go to an array. Finally, sort the array and pass the values to Sheet2.

Comment: If you dump the result of the recordset into Excel, you could also create a SQL-query against that data (but of course you need to create a new connection object).

Comment: Why don't you use formulas to aggregate the data on sheet 2?

Comment: Wont this just be `select sum(col1), count(*), sum(col2) from table1 group by 1,2 order by 1,2` if you're using select *?